How to convert HDR HEVC mov files to WebM for Wikipedia videos (on a Mac)
I have a series of HDR HEVC .mov files taken with an iPhone in BT.2020 colour space.
I want to publish them on Wikipedia which requires VP9 WebM files.
I am converting them on a Mac using Handbrake.
When I playback the original mov file in Quicktime, I see an HDR video file.
When I playback the original mov in VLC, I cannot see the HDR effect -the colours look more muted and the dynamic range is less.
I have converted the file to VP9 webm using BT2020 colour space. When I playback the converted file in VLC it also looks more muted and lower dynamic range.

Is it possible to playback WebM files at HDR on a mac to verify they have converted correctly? Quicktime cannot play WebM files. VLC can, but doesn't appear to playback HDR correctly.
Can Wikipedia handle HDR files? Their site says they handle VP9 which includes the BT2020 colourspace.
Any advice on workflow would be appreciated, but it needs to be on a Mac.

Just seen VLC 3 doesn't support HDR colour rendering, but should be fixed in v4: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=165034&p=545919&hilit=HDR#p545919 is there a webm player for the mac that can?
